# Minimum SDK is not recognized in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels

I've just installed Android Studio 3.0 and all of the APIs and all of the available sources(API 14 or higher were only available options) but when I'm trying to create a new project based on Android 2.3.3 (API 10), this API isn't available in the selection list of minimum SDK.

where is the problem?

What should I do?

Thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: What are your reasons for supporting such an old version of Android?

Comment: Because I'm working on a project that aims not developed areas that may have not access to the most recent version of Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the minimum SDK for most of the Android support libraries has increased to 14.

> Caution: Starting with Support Library release 26.0.0 (July 2017), the minimum supported API level across most support libraries has increased to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for most library packages.

You could manually edit the minSdk in your `app/build.gradle` but you'd also have to ensure you're using an older version of the support libraries.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html

Comment: So you say that officially making an app for lower android versions are not possible?

Comment: it is possible - you can manually reduce the minSdk value in your `app/build.gradle`, but you'll not be able to use the latest official support-libraries.